# Ошибка 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
            for i in range (len(transport)+1):
                print ('Transport: ' + str (transport[i]) + '   That transport cost ' + str (transport_cost[i]) + ' (if you want to buy it, you can write user ' + str (transport_users [i]) + ').')
```

пишу так, выдает ошибку:

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Переменная `transport` указывает на `None`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, или `transport_cost`, или `transport_users`

Comment: то есть переменная transport пуста?

Comment: Проблема точно не в transport, иначе упало бы ещё в предыдущей строчке на len(transport). А вот transport_cost и transport_users нужно проверить, одна из них точно None

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @Xander оказывается я по ошибке написал так: transport_users = file.close()          ☺